# Firebase FieldPath.documentId() where query issue

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query my firebase db using the below code but keep getting docuemtnID is undefined. Is my syntax way off as I keep getting **Cannot read property 'documentId' of undefined**

```
 db.collection("listings")
   .where(db.FieldPath.documentId(), "==", element.drawId)
   .get()
   .then(docRef => {
      
   });
```

Firebase is imported as `import { db } from "../firebase/init";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access `FieldPath` as a property of the `db` instance.  Without seeing what's in `../firebase/init`, it's not possible to say for sure what you need to use instead (as we can't see how you imported/required the Firestore module).  In JavaScript web clients, you would typically say `firebase.firestore.FieldValue`.

But it's worth noting that since queries using `FieldPath.documentId()` are only ever going to return a single document with the given ID, you could just `get()` it instead, and be much more clear and concise:

```
db.collection("listings").doc(element.drawId).get().then(...)
```

See: [Get a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document)

Comment: Thank you Doug for that, led me to the right place and now I can get my document nicely.